# cannot be built from an iterator over elements of type `()`

Tags: rust

This program is for printing parallel running thread. Print all start thread before end thread. But this program throw error `the trait` FromIterator<()> `is not implemented for Vec<JoinHandle<>> the trait FromIterator<T> is implemented for Vec<T>`. What's wrong with this program? Any feedback helps a lot.

```
let handles: Vec<JoinHandle<String>> = (0..=10).map(|i| {
        let delay = rand::thread_rng().gen_range(10..=2000);
        let builder =
          thread::Builder::new().name(format!("Thread-{}", i));
        
        builder.spawn(move || {
          println!(
            "thread started = {}",
            thread::current().name().unwrap()
          );
          thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(delay));
          thread::current().name().unwrap().to_owned()
        }).unwrap();
      }).collect();

for h in handles {
  let r = h.join().unwrap();
  println!("thread done = {:?}", r);
}
```

[rust-playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=df4e285dbea5da4a9783272d72870495)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the last value of a function (be it a top-level function or a closure) to be returned implicitly, you should *not* end it with a semicolon. Semicolons terminate statements that are being run for effects, not the final expression of a returning function. Replace

```
builder.spawn(move || {
  ...
}).unwrap();
```

with

```
builder.spawn(move || {
  ...
}).unwrap() // <- No semicolon :)
```